# How can I detect camera button pressed on usbvideo device and allow sharing of the device with another application?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, video, camera

I am writing a program that will monitor a video camera on a usbvideo driver and find out when the camera button is pressed. I just want notification of the event, not the stream or image. I can make it work with C# and directshow net library but it stops other programs from accessing the camera.

My success has been using AForge  Videdo DirectShow library. A snippet of the code is (which is about the entire program)

```
    videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
    videoDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
    snapshotCapabilities = videoDevice.SnapshotCapabilities;
    videoCapabilities = videoDevice.VideoCapabilities;

    videoDevice.ProvideSnapshots = true;
    videoDevice.SnapshotResolution = snapshotCapabilities[0];
    videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[0];

    videoDevice.SnapshotFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cameraButtonEvent);

    videoDevice.Start();
```

The cameraButtonEvent handler gets called each time the camera button is pressed. However, no other application can access the camera.

Comment: You need to provide more info regarding what research you have done so far, platform information, sample code, and anything that will narrow down the variety of where your questions can lead everyone.

Comment: I have added the code for more specific details of my code.